# Windows RPC Remote Abort Shutdown

Tags: windows, rpc, shutdown, abort

I'm able to remotely shutdown my windows 10 machine via RPC by executing following code:
`net rpc shutdown -I 192.168.xx.xx -U User%PWD`

Sometimes, however, it would be convinient to remotely abort the shutdown too.

But, neither
`net rpc shutdown -a -I 192.168.xx.xx -U User%PWD`
nor
`net rpc abortshutdown -I 192.168.xx.xx -U User%PWD`
seem to work anyhow.

It just gives me `Could not initialise pipe winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

What is the right way to abort an shutdown via rpc? Or am I missing some Rights?

Answer (score 0):

Run `services.msc` --> find `Remote Registry` --> startup type: `Automatic` --> `Start`